# Scala - Correct syntax when not working with Optional with map and fold

Tags: scala

What is the correct syntax to implement the following code without use an Optional object?

I was doing a "double check" and it's not necessary to use Optional because the object never will be Nil.

```
case class Node(key:Int,
            children:List[Node] = Nil,
            valid:Option[Boolean] = Some(false))

def rankingChildren(node:Option[Node], score:Double = 0, depth:Int = 0):Double =
  node
    .map(_.children.filter(n => n.valid == Some(true)).fold(score)((acc, h) =>
      rankingChildren(Some(h.asInstanceOf[Node]), acc.asInstanceOf[Double] + 1)
    .getOrElse(score).asInstanceOf[Double]
```

I've tried to:

```
def rankingChildren(node:Node, score:Double = 0, depth:Int = 0): Double =
  node.children.filter(n => n.valid == Some(true)).fold[Double](score)((acc, h) =>
      rankingChildren(h.asInstanceOf[Node], acc.asInstanceOf[Double] + 1, depth + 1))
```

But i got another error on compilation:

```
Error:(75, 60) type arguments [Double] do not conform to method fold's type parameter bounds [A1 >: models.Node]
  node.children.filter(n => n.valid == Some(true)).fold[Double](score)((acc, h) =>
```

How can i change it and is possible to avoid casts using fold()?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the definition of Node.

Comment: Check the edit, pls

Comment: If i change fold() to foldLeft() it works and save my life :). But why should i use fold or foldLeft?

Comment: If you check out the two methods signatures you might see why
`def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1`
and
`def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B`

as you see, `fold` has a requirement `[A1 >: A]` for the result.

Comment: Any big difference using fold or foldLeft?

Comment: It's funny to note that `fold` is actually implemented using `foldLeft` :)

Comment: Sorry for the dumb questions but i'm really new to functional programming and scala hehe